# Flutter How set images fit to custom image frame?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to set images to my custom frame(frame is a png file) like image below.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYQKX.png)

image reference (https://favpng.com/png_view/film-strips-photographic-film-filmstrip-photography-photo-booth-png/EDuYNtkt)

Answer (score 0):

use can try this it will help

```
Expanded(
      // your image goes here which will take as much height as possible.
      child: Image.asset('asset', fit: BoxFit.contain), 
    ),
```

or

```
Image.asset('asset', fit: BoxFit.fill)
```

Comment: I means, I have images and png frame and then I want to fill images to frame like the links below. 
Thanks.
https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61qdk6g-3mL._AC_SX466_.jpg
https://photoboothrocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/hands-holding-photo-booth-strips-683x1024.jpeg

Comment: FittedBox(
  child: Image.asset('foo.png'),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
) check if your looking like this